# Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich JNI jclass arg has wrong type

Tags: java-native-interface, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

JNI WARNING: jclass arg has wrong type (expected Ljava/lang/Class;, got Lcom/my/app/MyClass;)
 in Lcom/my/app/MyClass;.myMethod:()V (SetStaticIntField)

This is my code

```
static jclass   myObject = NULL;

static BOOL init(JNIEnv *env)
{
     jclass* localClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/my/app/MyClass");
     myObject = (jclass*)(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, localClass);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_my_app_MyClass_myMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
        int position = getPosition(); /* the value is set at 1*/
    (*env)->SetStaticIntField(env, obj, position_field_id, position);
}
```

My application works fine in Android 2.1, 2.1, 2.3.x; but when I use it on Android 4.0 it crashes and shows the warning I mention at the beginning.

When I comment out the line the application runs but it will probably break something else.

Tried changing jobject to jclass but does not work.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to pass a class instead of an object on SetStaticField

jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);

It seems Android 4 does not like jni warnings